# Passing images to Keras' CNN model with 6 channels

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm having trouble with `Keras imagedatagenerator` class. I want to pass it an image with 6 channels to train background subtraction - I have the image stacked depthwise with its background, which is calculated using SubSense algorithm. This gives an image of shape `(X,X,6)` instead of two images with `(X,X,3)`

But `opencv` doesn't really let you save this so I had to save it as  a `numpy` file. Now I want to get that `numpy` file into Keras as an image for training a CNN that will eventually return just the foreground masks but obviously trying to run it through ImageDataGenerator returns 0 images because it has too many channels.

My code is:

```
all_files = os.listdir("null/train")
arr=[]

for i in all_files:
    file_path= "null/train/" + i
    X = np.load(file_path)
    arr.append (X)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

datagen.fit(arr)
```

The resulting Error was:

> null/anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py:940: UserWarning: Expected input to be images (as Numpy array) following the data format convention "channels_last" (channels on axis 3), i.e. expected either 1, 3 or 4 channels on axis 3. However, it was passed an array with shape (451, 321, 321, 6) (6 channels).
>     ' channels).')

Is there a way to force it to take `numpy` files with 6 channels?

Answer (score 0):

for your case, you need to modify the preprocessing_function which reads your rank 3 image as input. whatever you are doing to make it 6 channel image, do that change inside that function. please see an example (I'm passing a 3 channel image in ImageGenerator).

**see below, arr is 3 channel image.I write a preProsFunc and assigned it to *preprocessing_function* of ImageGenerator. I am just concatenating so as to make 6 channel image. similarly you can write your logic inside proprocessing_function**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((4,4,3))
arr = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=0)

def preProsFunc(arr):
  arr1 = np.zeros((4,4,3))
  arr1 = np.expand_dims(arr1, axis=0)
  return np.concatenate((arr, arr1), axis=2)

datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    preprocessing_function=preProsFunc
    )

datagen.fit(arr)
```

let me know for anything.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! Your code prevented an immediate error when I ran it. Two questions though 1) don't you mean to concatenate on axis=3? Because this result gives something like (321,642,3)? Also, we are not concatenating with a generic array but with a specific background array for each image (so input1.jpg + bg1.jpg). So we would still need to pass a 6 channel array or two parameters to the preprocessing function but that doesn't seem to work. This way would only ever work if I used the same database.

Comment: ImageGenerator is written to read with either 1, 3 or 4 channels on axis 3(channel_last). Ideally we shouldn't modify how ImageGenerator takes input, rather you should write a separate function which do all the stuff regarding stacking depthwise with its background, using SubSense algorithm, and align that whole function to preprocessing_function.  it should work because whatever you were doing with a 3d image to make it 6, that thing now happens inside processing_function. pls try and let me know if this thing works

Comment: I see. The problem with this method is that generating the background (which is what the SubSense algorithm does) takes a lot of time all on its own. The stacking was done by taking the two images (input and background) and using np.dstack, that is not the hard part. Training already takes a long time. In this situation, if I put the bg generation in preprocessing, I would have to run the algorithm fresh on every image in the training set whenever I wanted to retrain or reuse the model (or change the input data), instead of running it once on a dataset and then having those files forever.